Why is the value not changing even after the command is run with ROOT?
Even after the command is run successfully with ROOT, the file's value doesn't change
I want to change /sys/class/lcd/panel/vrr value to 65 0
where it is 60 0 by default
For this I first set enforcing to 0 with su -c setenforce 0
Still shows enforcing when I run getenforce
Let's move on,
Then I tried
su -c 'echo "65 0" > /sys/class/lcd/panel/vrr'
Ran successfully
But when I run su -c 'cat /sys/class/lcd/panel/vrr' to check,
Value shows 60 0
My attempt was to overclock the display refresh rate of my android device display by 5Hz
You can do that really easily on PCs with CRU, overclocked my 60Hz display to 95Hz.
I thought I could do it on android too.
I think the system ignores it.
Can we do it ? Asking for help from experts.

If the hardware does not support it, you cannot do it
